# Merging PHP codes

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to combine 1 part of my PHP code into another part, and I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

This is the code:

```
        <?php
        if (is_single()) {
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                // get thumbnail
                wikiwp_get_thumbnail($post);
        ?>
<div>This should stay here in a post</div>
<div>And this should also be visible in this case</div>


       <?php
            endwhile;
        } else {

        ?>

<div>This should stay here in a page</div>

        <?php
        } 
        ?>
```

I want to add the first bit of php into the endwhile.
I want to put this bit:

```
                <?php
                if (is_page()) {
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                        // get thumbnail
                        wikiwp_get_thumbnail($post);
                ?>
```

into this part: (without breaking the code)

```
           <?php
                endwhile;
            } else {

            ?>
```

The result is:
If its a single post it will show:

```
[thumbnail] 
This should stay here 
And this should also be visible in this case
```

If its a page it will show:

```
[thumbnail] 
This should stay here on a page
```

Comment: You may need: `https://wordpress.org/support/topic/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the_post-for-page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<?php

if (is_single() || is_page()) {
    while (have_posts()):
        the_post();

        # page + post
        wikiwp_get_thumbnail($post);

        # post only
        if (is_single()) {
?>

<div>This should stay here in a post</div>
<div>And this should also be visible in this case</div>

<?php
        } else if (is_page()) {
?>

<div>This should stay here in a page</div>

<?php
        }
    endwhile;
} else {
?>

<div>This is neither a page or post!</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would give an output no matter what. 
1st output is for posts (is_single() )
2nd output is for pages (is_page() )
3rd output is for anything else?

Comment: Yes, that's the logic but ths code is not tested. I'm not 100% sure that `while (have_posts()):` will work with pages on wordpress. Hence: `https://wordpress.org/support/topic/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the_post-for-page‌`

Comment: The goal is to show the thumbnail on pages as well as posts, but with different content. When its a post I want the thumbnail + author, date etc.etc.
But when its a page, I want the thumbnail + nothing.
I'll give this a go and see what happens.

Comment: I've used your code in the sidebar, and it seems to work perfectly fine. I'll have to try some more things before I can be 100% sure, but from first glance it works just how I want.

Comment: If it shows the thumbnail on pages, then it works inside pages too :) Don't forget to accept my answer later if it works as you expect.

Comment: Have tried it in many ways and many forms, and the code seems to be solid. Everything is working fine with no errors or whatever. So I thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided, merged together, would look like this:

```
<?php
    if (is_single()) {
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            // get thumbnail
            wikiwp_get_thumbnail($post);
?>
            <div>This should stay here in a post</div>
            <div>And this should also be visible in this case</div>
<?php
        endwhile;
    } else {
        if (is_page()) {
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            // get thumbnail
            wikiwp_get_thumbnail($post);
?>
            <div>This should stay here in a page</div>
<?php
        }
    } 
?>
```

Note that this will **not** output anything if it's not a single post or a page.

Comment: Thank you. I'm starting to see how you did it. You put the code behind the ELSE and then closed it in the last bit of php. Feel stupid for not thinking of that.
Would the solution given by peixotorms give a result even if its not a single post or page?

Comment: The other answer would work also.  It's a slightly different approach, but the same net result.

Comment: And - to answer your question directly - the other answer will output something if it's neither page nor post.  It could be modified to *not* output, and mine could be modified *to* output, if desired.

Comment: Thank you for your help Cale_b. I'm gonna try the other answer first, if needed I'll get back to you to see how to get an output.